# Trying to Download Heroku Database to Local: Connection to Database Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) documentation to try to pull my Heroku database to my localhost.  I already successfully ran `heroku pg:backups:capture` and `heroku pg:backups:download` and see a `latest.dump` file in my file structure.

However, when I try to run `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump` I get the following error:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?  could not connect to server: Connection refused      
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the `mydb` database during restoration, you need the `--create` option. Otherwise, the command looks for an existing db named `mydb` which doesn't seem to exist, according to the error message.